# Not able to read external file using D3.js

Tags: javascript, python, csv, d3.js, flask

I am not able to read data from csv or json file using D3JS in my Flask application.

Here is the code of:

HTML:

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>D3JS</title>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

    d3.csv("../data.csv", function (data) {
        console.log(data); 
    });

</script>

</body>
```

Flask app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('historgram.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am receiving file not found error. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: is the file really called historgram (sic)

Comment: it was a typo Robert, by the was it was not spelling mistakes :) Thanks for pointing out anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `data.csv` is static data, you have to move the file into a directory `static/` accessible from your flask server and access it via

```
d3.csv("/static/data.csv", function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: thanks .. it worked :) I don't know how I missed this out.